# How can I display data in my Calendar using Full Calendar and Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to display my data on the Calendar. I'm using Full Calendar and Vue js. I'm successfully retrieving the data, I'm using a service.file that is making the api request, which loads the data and it's being loaded into events: ''. This is done in Laravel/php on the backend. If you need to see this code let me know but it's just returning everything from my interviews table into json. When I console.log() I can see the data and I'm trying to bind it on the `<Fullcalendar />` component as seen below, but I can't get it to show in the calendar.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <Fullcalendar :plugins="calendarPlugins" :events="events" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    import Fullcalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
    import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
    import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
    import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
    import * as employerInterviewService from '../services/employer_interview_service.js';

export default {

        components: {
            Fullcalendar
        },

        data() {
            return {
                calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
                events: "",
            };
        },

        created() {
            this.getEvents();
        },

        methods: {

            getEvents: async function() {
                const response = await employerInterviewService.loadInterviews();
                this.events = response.data.events;

                console.log(this.events);

            },

        },

    };
</script>
```

Comment: If you replace your data with a test local ones it still won;t work?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the column in my table from `start_date` to `start` and my `title` column in my tables were empty. I added some data to them and now it's working. –

Comment: Yeah you have to match the fields which fullCalendar expects, otherwise it doesn't know where to look to find the important pieces of data in your objects

Comment: What if I want to display other data in there? For example, in my form I have 'date2' input , with a date2 column in my table. So the person can select 2 possible dates, until one of them is confirmed. How can I display date2 value like we do start value? Or for example if in my form I had 'time' input field, and in my table I had a 'time' column, so the user can select a date and time. How can I display the 'time' value on the calendar?

Comment: All other non-standard properties which you supply in the event's JSON go into the extendedProps object of the fullCalendar event (see the Event Parsing page in the documentation). If you want to use those and display them on the calendar you can customise the appearance of your events via the eventRender callback (again there's an article on it in the documentation).

Comment: Do you have an example of this on JS Fiddle? What would the code look like? Like this?
```
events: {
                    extendedProps: {
                        allDay: false,
                    },
                },
```

Comment: allDay is a standard, documented property, so you certainly wouldn't want to put that in extendedProps. But anyway, as I said, fullCalendar will create extendedProps for you, you don't have to create it yourself - you can supply all of your event's properties as a flat list and fullCalendar will transform the structure when it copies your properties to a fullCalendar event object.

Comment: P.S. you said "How can I display the 'time' value on the calendar?"...events already have times. The time will show up automatically. Here's a nice simple demo showing extendedProps and eventRender (and showing the time showing up automatically when it's part of the start / end dates): https://jsfiddle.net/z9354ah8/1/

Comment: Thanks, I see how the time works and I have it showing in the Calendar. It was showing in all views Month, Week, Day and List, but now all of a sudden, It's only showing in Month view. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: you mean the time was? No I don't know how it could happen. You'd have to provide your calendar code, preferably in the form of a runnable demo.